# Adding to a plugin's options

Tags: woocommerce, plugins

having  bit of trouble adding an option to reduce stock on a product within a deposit plugin (woo commerce deposits). Currently the options as standard are: 'deposit' or 'full payment' - I wish to also add 'both deposit or full payment' so stock would be reduced if either deposit or full payment is taken.

Help, much appreciated!

Updated function#1:

```
 public function payment_complete_reduce_order_stock($reduce, $order_id) {
 $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
 $status = $order->get_status();
 $reduce_on = get_option('wc_deposits_reduce_stock', 'full');

 if ($status === 'partially-paid' && $reduce_on === 'full') {
   $reduce = false;
 }
 else if ($status !== 'partially-paid' && $reduce_on === 'deposit') {
   $reduce = false;
 } //added in...
 else if ( $status == 'partially-paid' && $reduce_on === 'both'){ // added to allow reduction on both Deposit and Full
  $reduce = true;
}
else  if ($status == !'partially-paid' && $order->wc_deposits_remaining_paid == 'yes') { // Added to NOT reduce if prepayment taken then completing order
    $reduce = false;           
}
```

Updated function#2:

```
'deposits_stock' => array(
      'name'  => __('Reduce Stocks On', 'woocommerce-deposits'),
      'type'  => 'radio',
      'desc'  => __('Choose when to reduce stocks.', 'woocommerce-deposits'),
      'id'    => 'wc_deposits_reduce_stock',
      'options' => array(
        'deposit' => __('Deposit Payment', 'woocommerce-deposits'),
        'full'    => __('Full Payment', 'woocommerce-deposits'),
        // added in...
        'both'    => __('Both Full Payment or Deposit', 'woocommerce-deposits')
      ),
      'default' => 'full'
    ),
```

This is where I think I fall down:

Original 'Save all settings' function:

```
$reduce_stock = isset($_POST['wc_deposits_reduce_stock']) ?
  ($_POST['wc_deposits_reduce_stock'] === 'deposit' ? 'deposit' : 'full') : 'full';
```

I'm not sure how to add in the additional option, this doesn't work!:

```
$reduce_stock = isset($_POST['wc_deposits_reduce_stock']) ?
  ($_POST['wc_deposits_reduce_stock'] === 'deposit' ? 'deposit' : 'full' ? 'both' : 'full' ) : 'full';
```

Comment: Just to say - I've got this working - it's just the selection in the admin options page that is acting strangely - It defaults to my new option - (which is great for me!), but would be good to know how to get it working properly for if/when it's needed.

Cheers